# segmentation fault when adding a new object to Openssl

Tags: c, openssl, segmentation-fault

I tried to add a new digest algorithm to a new defined engine in Openssl.I have added new nids to file `crypto/objects/obj_mac.num`:

```
simple_cipher           920
id_simple_cipher                921
```

and added this line to `crypto/objects/object.txt`:

```
!Cname id-simple_cipher
cryptopro 100           : simple_cipher                 : SIMPLE 28147-89
```

and this to `lvalues` array :

```
0x2A,0x85,0x03,0x02,0x02,0x64,               /* [5973] OBJ_id_simple_cipher */
```

and when I compiled Openssl the following lines was added to file `crypto/objects/obj_mac.h`:

```
#define SN_id_simple_cipher             "simple_cipher"
#define LN_id_simple_cipher             "SIMPLE 28147-89"
#define NID_id_simple_cipher            921
#define OBJ_id_simple_cipher            OBJ_cryptopro,100L
```

and these two lines to `nid_objs` array in `crypto/objects/obj_dat.h`:

```
{NULL,NULL,NID_undef,0,NULL,0},
{"simple_cipher","SIMPLE 28147-89",NID_id_simple_cipher,6,
        &(lvalues[5973]),0},
```

and also nid is added to the other arrays in this file.

but when I try to load engine or run this command `openssl engine -c engine-name` I cause segmentation fault. I think it's because of the added cipher and I'm doing something wrong while defining new nid for cipher. 
there is an array in file `engines/simple/eng_simple.c` (where my engine is defined) named `gost_cipher_nids` when I add my new defined nid to this array this seg fault happens.
I'm new to openssl I really appreciate any help.
I'm working with version `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips`

Comment: Have you identified what is wrong here ?